# UltiSnips expand java package

Tags: java, vim, ultisnips

I want to be able to write a vim snippet that automatically turns into the required package.

E.g. expanding `pkg` while inside of `.../com/theonlygust/project/Main.java` would become

```
package com.theonlygusti.project;
```

I think the ways to do this are to either: read up the directory tree until seeing a TLD directory name (com, io, net, etc.) and then use the encountered directory names to build the package string, or to look up the directory tree for the `pom.xml` and find the package from there.

I learned about python interpolation.

I'm now trying this:

```
snippet pkg "Create package" b
package `!p

import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def get_package_name(pom_file_path):
  namespaces = {'xmlns' : 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}

  tree = ElementTree.parse(pom_file_path)
  root = tree.getroot()

  groupId = root.find(".//xmlns:groupId", namespaces=namespaces)
  artifactId = root.find(".//xmlns:artifactId", namespaces=namespaces)
  return groupId.text + '.' + artifactId.text

def find_nearest_pom():
  absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('__file__')).split("/")
  pom_dir_index = -1

  # Find index of 'base_dir_name' element
  while not os.path.isfile('/'.join(absolute_path[:pom_dir_index]) + '/pom.xml'):
    pom_dir_index -= 1

  return '/'.join(absolute_path[:pom_dir_index]) + '/pom.xml'

snip.rv = get_package_name(find_nearest_pom())`;
endsnippet
```

But I get the error

> Name `__file__` does not exist

And `os.getcwd()` doesn't work because that returns the directory from which vim was opened, not the directory that contains the current buffer.

I had a look at the `snip` object because I know it provides `snip.fn` to get the filename, but I couldn't find out if it provides the current file's directory.

Nevermind, finally learned that UltiSnips sets a global variable "`path`"

Comment: you have completely changed the question after I provided an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a combination of the file path and the groupId and the artifactId from the nearest pom.xml (upwards)

```
global !p
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def get_package_name(pom_file_path):
  namespaces = {'xmlns' : 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}

  tree = ElementTree.parse(pom_file_path)
  root = tree.getroot()

  groupId = root.find(".//xmlns:groupId", namespaces=namespaces)
  artifactId = root.find(".//xmlns:artifactId", namespaces=namespaces)
  return groupId.text + '.' + artifactId.text

def find_nearest_pom():
  current_file_dir = '/'.join((os.getcwd() + ('/' if os.getcwd()[-1] != '/' else '') + path).split('/')[:-1])
  absolute_path = current_file_dir.split("/")
  pom_dir_index = -1

  if os.path.isfile('/'.join(absolute_path) + '/pom.xml'):
    return '/'.join(absolute_path) + '/pom.xml'

  # Find index of 'base_dir_name' element
  while not os.path.isfile('/'.join(absolute_path[:pom_dir_index]) + '/pom.xml'):
    pom_dir_index -= 1

  return '/'.join(absolute_path[:pom_dir_index]) + '/pom.xml'

def get_file_package():
  current_file_location = '.'.join((os.getcwd() + ('/' if os.getcwd()[-1] != '/' else '') + path).split('/')[:-1])
  package = get_package_name(find_nearest_pom())
  return package + current_file_location.split(package)[1]

endglobal

snippet pkg "package" b
package `!p snip.rv = get_file_package()`;
endsnippet
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be achieve using regex?

like this:

```
global !p

def get_file_package():
    input_str = vim.eval('expand("%:p")')
    transformed_str = re.sub(r'^.*/src/(test|main)/java/((.+/)*)(.*?)/.*\.java$', r'\3\4', input_str)
    return re.sub('/', '.', transformed_str)

endglobal

snippet pkg "Declare java package" b
package `!p snip.rv = get_file_package()`;
endsnippet
```

I using this, tell if I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

UltiSnips stores Java snippets in [java.snippets](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/1cb5639b78bc3685baf18b03859335143a86114c/UltiSnips/java.snippets), which on my machine is `~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/java.snippets (I am using`honza/vim-snippets` as well).

Snippets for Java are implemented using Python, so I have implemented the snippet below using Python as well (you can do it using multiple languages in UltiSnips).

There is already a snippet for `package`, which adds simply "package" word followed with a placeholder:

```
snippet pa "package" b
package $0
endsnippet
```

Let's create a `pad` snippet that will automatically insert package name, based on the directory chain, instead of the `$0` placeholder:

```
snippet pad "package" b
package `!p

def get_package_string(base_dir_name):
  import os
  # Get absolute path of the package (without filename)
  absolute_path = os.getcwd().split("/")
  src_dir_index = 0

  # Find index of 'base_dir_name' element
  while absolute_path[src_dir_index] != base_dir_name:
    src_dir_index+=1

  # Create a 'package ' string, joining with dots
  package_string = ".".join(absolute_path[src_dir_index+1:])
  return package_string

# snip.rv is UltiSnips' return value we want to paste between ``
snip.rv = get_package_string("java")`

endsnippet
```

Note that this solution is based on the fact that in many Java projects, there is an `src` directory with `main/java` and `test/java` directories in it and you are editing one of the files in `java` directory (e.g. for `src/main/com/google/common` it will return `com.google.common`). You may need to modify this to be more flexible.

You can find more information about creating snippets in [screencasts linked in its README](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/tree/1cb5639b78bc3685baf18b03859335143a86114c#screencasts).

Comment: I get `name __file__ is not defined`

Comment: Since `__file__` doesn't work in your case, you may want to try: `import inspect; filename = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))`.

Comment: `os.getcwd()` doesn't work, it gets the directory from which `vim` was opened, not the directory where the currently-opened buffer exists.

Comment: @minseong I see you've completely changed the question (previously it didn't have any code). I think you should ask another question instead.